# PHP MySQL insert statement not executing

Tags: php, mysql, insert

Apologies, for the noobie question. Is there an insert limit for the number of records in a SQL statement?

I'm using a web form to add rows of data. I'm not using limit in the insert statement. I checked 'max_allowed_packet' which is currently 268435456 and I don't think that's the problem.

Here is a sample of my insert statement, which works fine if there are fewer than 100 rows.

INSERT INTO tbl_sample (id, status_timestamp, submit_ts, status_desc, comment) VALUES ('', now(), now(), 'Submitted', '')

After entering the form data, I am losing variables after submit and the insert never executes. I've never had this happen before and can't figure it out. Variables are there before submitting. Would appreciate suggestions.

Comment: It looks like your insert statement should only insert one row.

Comment: Records are inserted using a for loop.